# Pandas read_csv() parses dates fine but can't index by date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

This is strange.

Data (csv):

```
Date,    Hr 1,Hr 2,Hr 3,..
20070701,1128,1072,1173,..
20070702,1131,1092,1287,..
```

Pretty vanilla use of pd.read_csv():

```py
df = pd.read_csv(   filename,
                    parse_dates=['Date'],
                    index_col=['Date'])
```

Date seems to parse fine into the index:

```py
print(df.index[:2])
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2007-07-01', '2007-07-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Now if I try to index a single day?

```py
print(df['2007-7-1']) # or any variation on "2007-07-01" etc
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mjw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '2007-7-1'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file.py", line 108, in <module>
    print(df['2007-7-1'])
  File "/Users/mjw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/mjw/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '2007-7-1'
```

I've also tried to make sure the DatetimeIndex freq is set right

```py
df = df.asfreq('d')
```

And I get the same junk.

But indexing by year and month works fine, or indexing by year-month-day after selecting a column:

```py
print(df['2007-7']) # works
print(df['Hr 1']['2007-7-1']) # works
```

But this does not:

```py
print(df['2007-7-1']['Hr 1'])
```

I can make a custom date parser but the point is that I shouldn't have to do that. "yyyymmdd" isn't exactly hard or unusual. Come on pandas.

Please and thank you!

Comment: something to try `df[:'2007-07-01'].head(2)` or `df['2007-07-01':'2007-07-01'].head(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc`:

```
print(df.loc["2007-07-01"])
```

Prints:

```
    Hr 1    1128
Hr 2        1072
Hr 3        1173
Name: 2007-07-01 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

For just value of "Hr 2" column:

```
print(df.loc["2007-07-01", "Hr 2"])
```

Prints:

```
1072
```

Comment: That works. Whats the difference. I successfully use `df['2007-7-1']` all the time elsewhere.

Comment: @Mike With `df['2007-7-1']` you are selecting column named `2007-7-1`

Comment: Then why does `df['2007-7']` return all the columns but only the rows `2007-7-1` through `2007-7-31`?

Said a different way: there are not columns named '2007-7-1` only (one) row.

Comment: @Mike Using `df['2007-7']` is deprecated feature of pandas. My version writes `/usr/src/app/example.py:51: FutureWarning: Indexing a DataFrame with a datetimelike index using a single string to slice the rows, like 'frame[string]', is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use 'frame.loc[string]' instead.` The correct way is to use `.loc`